# How to write a particular rspec test? Advice needed ...

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, sinatra, rspec2

I'm new to rspec and I'm trying understand how to write some particular tests.

Background:

- I'm testing a Sinatra app
- That app connects to several databases
- I've defined the usernames/passwords for these databases as environment variables and I reference these variables in the code.

I have working test, so I know how to test for the existence of the environment variables.

Here's how I did it:

```
27     it "should know the username for each SUBDOMAIN in the list" do
28       @dm.domains.each do |dom|
29         ENV['C_USERNAME_' + dom].nil?.should eq(false)
30       end
31     end
```

As I said, the test works.  The only problem is, when it fails, its unclear which dom doesn't have the environment variable set.  The result of the failed test looks the following:

```
    dhaskew@Air1:~/code/projects/rules$ rake spec
   /Users/dhaskew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/c_spec.rb   ./spec/main_spec.rb ./spec/routes_spec.rb
   ..F*.....*

    Pending:
      My Site Domain Manager should know the password for each SUBDOMAIN in the list
      # Not yet implemented
      # ./spec/c_spec.rb:33
      My Site GET '/rules/SUBDOMAINS' should test all subdomains
      # Not yet implemented
      # ./spec/routes_spec.rb:28

   Failures:

     1) My Site Domain Manager should know the username for each SUBDOMAIN in the list
        Failure/Error: ENV['C_USERNAME_' + dom].nil?.should eq(false)

          expected: false
          got: true

          (compared using ==)
         # ./spec/c_spec.rb:29:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # ./spec/c_spec.rb:28:in `each'
         # ./spec/c_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

     Finished in 0.05095 seconds
     10 examples, 1 failure, 2 pending

    Failed examples:

    rspec ./spec/c_spec.rb:27 # My Site Domain Manager should know the username for each SUBDOMAIN in the list
    rake aborted!
```

Question: How do I write this test(s) better so that I can see which environment variable isn't defined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy solution is this: Generate the `it` tests dynamically. In general, strive for one test per scenario/`it` block. In this case:

```
@dm.domains.each do |dom|
  it "should know the username for #{dom} in the list" do
    ENV['C_USERNAME_' + dom].should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

## Update

Here's a more complete example. You need to declare `@dm` outside of a `before` block for it to be available.

```
class DomainManager
  attr_reader :domains

  def initialize(domains)
    @domains = domains
  end
end

describe DomainManager do
  @dm = DomainManager.new( %w(example.com example.org))

  @dm.domains.each do |dom|
    it "should know the username for #{dom} in the list" do
      ENV['C_USERNAME_' + dom].should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried that originally and could not get it to work.  The basic error I received is "undefined method `domains' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)", which suggests that @dm is out of scope? I had defined it in a before block at the top                                   '12   before(:all) do
 13     @dm = C::DomainManager.new
 14   end'

Comment: @David: Variables defined in `before` blocks are only available in `it` blocks. However, RSpec is just Ruby code, so you can just define your instance variable at the top. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, that got me working.  I'll be using the pattern a lot most likely.  I still need to read up on rspec related scoping, but I definitely over thought the situation.  Thanks for the simple example.

Comment: @David: Great, glad it worked for you. Definitely check out using contexts, implicit subjects, and more! Here are a few links to get you started: [rspec-2-best-practices slides](http://www.slideshare.net/andrea.reginato/rspec-2-best-practices) and  [another best practices](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/03/28/my-rspec-best-practices-and-tips/) post. Happy spec'ing!